# monitoring files and directories in C under windows

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, file-io, monitor

There is a way to monitor directories for changes like FileSystemWatcher but in C?

NOTE: I (have to) use gcc.

Comment: @Deanna : is not a duplicate, my question is taged winapi, the other is in linux environment.

Comment: Noted. Nice of them to add suitable tags and use Windows naming conventions.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417(v=vs.85).aspx) or [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx).