# Architecture solution about snapshotting file system

Tags: architecture

Please help me to think around a problem. I have an app (let us call it `X`) written in C++/Qt that should store and periodically update information about all apps installed on user's system. On Linux, it takes too much time to parse all `.desktop` files according to the `FreeDesktop.org` recomendations – about 2-3 seconds on my computer. So, I decided to use caching to work with files.

**How does caching should work:**

(Note, *app file* is a file that contains information about an app installed on user's system. For example, on Linux it may be `.desktop` file, on Windows – `.lnk` file, etc.)

1. At start, we have a list of directories when *app files* are located on user's system (for example, on Linux the list includes `/usr/share/application` directory).
2. As `X` starts, it goes through all folders in that list and creates a "snapshot" of all files. Snapshot should be a list of records that include file's full paths and `last modified` times. Then, `X` parses all that files in the snapshot and saves necessary information in, assume, `appsInformation` list.
3. After certain time goes, `X` creates a new snapshot of files in that folders. Then, it compares the new snapshot with the old one and creates three lists of changes: `added` list, that contains all *app files* that exist in the new snapshot but doesn't in the old one; `modified` list, that contains all *app files* with changed `last modified` time; and `deleted` list, that contains all *app files* that exist in the old snapshot but doesn't in the new one. After that, it parses information from new files in `added` list and pushes it back to `appsInformation` list, changes already existing records in `appsInformation` list according to `modified` list, and deletes existing records in `appsInformation` list that match files in `deleted` list.

So, I need to have two snapshots of file system with one of them somehow connected to `appsInformation` list.

Here goes my question: **what methods and tools should I use to construct all this architecture the best?** In the result, working with snapshots should be at least two times faster than parsing *all* files. I thought about some ideas but they are really ugly and hard-releasable. Should I use a couple of `QList`s of objects each of which contains a file information and a pointer to a `appsInformation` record? Or there is a better idea? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use polling in the first place. Instead, I'd use some callback-based file system monitoring library. Both Windows as well as Linux have this already, see the answers to these questions:

- [Best way to monitor file system changes in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381566/best-way-to-monitor-file-system-changes-in-linux)
- [monitoring files and directories in C under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808907/monitoring-files-and-directories-in-c-under-windows)

The callback which you install with these libraries usually not only gets told which file changed, but also some details about the change; i.e. a file was added, removed - or changed. So depending on the 'change type' you could add/remove/modify elements in your `appsInformationList`.